# Deleting duplicate data mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We have duplicate id where in if we use

```
SELECT MAX(id), COUNT(id) AS count 
FROM user_status 
GROUP BY user_id, user_type 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

we get the duplicate data

Now when I tried to insert it in delete via

```
DELETE 
FROM user_status 
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id), COUNT(id) AS count 
             FROM user_status 
             GROUP BY user_id, user_type 
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            )
```

I got the following error

```
Operand should contain 1 column
```

How can I fix this ? TIA

Comment: From error, it is obvious that it expects only one column in the `IN` clause. On the other hand, you are `SELECT`ing two columns. Now do you want to remove all the id(s) which are duplicates, or just leave one and delete rest of the duplicates ?

Comment: leave one sir ...

Comment: can a `user_id` have multiple `user_type` ?

Comment: @Beginner Have you noticed the comments of your accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As message is clear that you are selecting two columns in the `subquery` which is not allowed in `IN` clause but still `mysql` shows some error in such from of query so please replace the query with join as below

```
DELETE us 
FROM user_status us
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id 
            FROM user_status 
            GROUP BY user_id, user_type HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t ON t.id = us.id
```

Comment: im having an error table 'user_status' is specified twice, both as a target for 'delete'

Comment: Sorry I just realized that `mysql` does not support `IN` such cases so please use the second query with join.

Comment: This will delete only one row corresponding to the maximum id value inside a group. As per [OP comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603410/deleting-duplicate-data-mysql/52603556#comment92141034_52603410), he wants to delete all the other duplicate rows, except the one having maximum id value.

Comment: Also, mysql *does* support selecting two columns in a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
DELETE user_status
FROM user_status LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(user_id) maxId
    FROM user_status
    GROUP BY user_type
) a ON maxId = user_id
WHERE maxId IS NULL;
```

In your code `where col1 in (select col1, col2)` the column count simply doesn't match. If you reference each selected column, it works in principle:

```
DELETE FROM user_status
WHERE (user_id, user_type) NOT IN (
    SELECT MAX(user_id) maxId, user_type
    FROM (select * from user_status) a
GROUP BY user_type);
```

Comment: Agreed. taken back the comment. Simplest solution imho then. +1